# How do i loop through certain number of IDs when calling a REST API url in state property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I am building an application using "Rick and Morty" REST API, In the documentation, it is stated that we can request any number of characters out of 493 characters using certain query string.

For example, the below URL can request character with the ids 34 and 56,but if we want to request more characters at a single time we have to provide all the id in the array, and there are total 493 characters

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/[34,56]

I have a CardList component which loops over card component and shows up the properties.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "./Card";

class CardList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    url: `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${[...Array(493).keys()]}`,
    character: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);

    this.setState({
      character: res.data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.character.map(character => (
          <Card
            key={character.id}
            id={character.id}
            name={character.name}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            gender={character.gender}
            type={character.type ? character.type : "Unknown"}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

What i want to do:

I want to write a function in the "state" which fill up the array from 1 to 493, but where do i write the function?

What i tried to do:

I tried to use template strings in the state and wrote a function to create a range for the array
like below

url: `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${function loop(){var x = 0; while(x<493){ x++ ; return x}}}

something like above, but i'm not sure if i can write a function like above in the template strings.

Help me out, please.

Comment: Why dont you write it in the componentDidMount?

Comment: sure but how do I pass it in the state?

Comment: You dont need to keep them in state. You wanna fetch multiple times and set the result in state :)

Comment: A detailed code would be much appreciated

Comment: Sure will post a simple solution in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your code is ok. You just don't need to keep anything in the state. In case you need to compute a different set of IDs I suggest you run the code in `componentDidMount()` right before your HTTP request via Axio or inside a method or a pure function:

```
  ...

  getUrl(count) {
    // Array indexes start from 0 we wanna map them and add 1
    // and at the end we join them with a comma `,`
    const ids = Array(count).fill(null).map((_, idx) => idx +1).join(','); // '1,2,3...,300'
    return `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/[${ids}]`;
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.getUrl(300));

    this.setState({
      character: res.data
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes this did the work, just one more thing, what if i want to write function name using template strings in the "state" and define the definiton in the componentDidMount(), why that wont work?

Comment: If you insist that you need to keep the url in the state why don't you just write your logic in the class constructor? That is the first place you can set the state. Infact what you see as state assignment is translated to the same in class constructor

Comment: Here is a [link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa1lifaAvGpltAG5ggCu8AXNAORIAWAljBMwPZUgAm0AEb5gXALYAHViHgCkXaKIB2yAE5V5qhgBoSAX3QllaqsE3QAFAEpipaC3YA6HHkdglXFvFUA1SjUJGAE9EBn10PSA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.4&externalPlugins=)
Updated the link

Comment: And to answer your question putting everything in the string template also should work.

Comment: very interesting, however, if I define my function name in the URL inside the "state" and write the logic for the function in the componentDidMount(), it wont work because the componentDidMount() loads up first, and it does not have any function name(which in the state actually) for the logic i have provided. I hope i am right

Comment: `componentDidMount()` is executed after React inserts the element into DOM so technically way after all the assignments of the class component. So again you can define a method to return the url in your class and then call that method in `componentDidMount()` and it should work :)

Comment: Updated the answer using a class method, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to do what you want, you're just missing the wrapping square brackets. Change to this:

```js
const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/[${[...Array(493).keys()]}]`;
```

By the way, there doesn't appear to be any reason to keep this in the state. Would recommend moving this to a constant outside of the state.

Comment: Yes this would work, but i wanted to write a function name there and later define the function into my componentDIdMount().. something as                                                              const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/[function loop()]`;                                           and later write the function definiton in the componentDidMount(), but i am sure i am doing something wrong here